# SQLAlchemy - SQLEndTran - PyODBC vs. Engine

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyodbc

This should be an easy one but driving me crazy.

I cannot share all the details but lets say I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
server='MyServer'
database='MyDB'
username = 'MyUser'
password = 'MyPWD'

# pyodbc connection string
connection_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};PORT=17001;DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'

# create sqlalchemy engine connection URL
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}))

pd.read_sql(sql=Query, con=engine)

ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111214;An attempt to complete a transaction has failed. No corresponding transaction found. (111214) (SQLEndTran)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

The link reads (I bolded the interesting bit):

> ProgrammingError Exception raised for programming errors, e.g. table
> not found or already exists, syntax error in the SQL statement, wrong
> number of parameters specified, etc.
>
> This error is a DBAPI Error and originates from the database driver
> (DBAPI), not SQLAlchemy itself.
>
> **The ProgrammingError is sometimes raised by drivers in the context of
> the database connection being dropped, or not being able to connect to
> the database. For tips on how to deal with this, see the section
> Dealing with Disconnects.**

I suppose the connection is to blame and not my `Query` (not shown) because if I do:

```
import pyodbc    
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
pd.read_sql(sql=Query, con=cnxn)
```

The query works fine, but I get the Pandas warning for not using SQLAlchemy:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9716\2299942033.py:1: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong when creating the `engine`?

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using ?

Comment: sqlalchemy.__version__
'1.4.44'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it... the following worked:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import sqlalchemy
    from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
    
    driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
    server='MyServer'
    database='MyDB'
    username = 'MyUser'
    password = 'MyPWD'
    
    # create sqlalchemy engine connection URL
    connection_url = connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", 
                                                  username=username, 
                                                  password=password, 
                                                  host=server, 
                                                  database=database, 
                     query={"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", "autocommit": "True"})
    
    pd.read_sql(sql=Query, con=engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sqlalchemy like this:

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    pd.read_sql(sql=Query, con=conn)
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, same result :-(

`ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111214;An attempt to complete a transaction has failed. No corresponding transaction found. (111214) (SQLEndTran)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)`